# subtract two arrays in Perl

Tags: perl

What's the idiomatic way to subtract two arrays in Perl? I don't write Perl very often, and I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
my @arr1 = ("a", "b","c",);
my @arr2 = ("a", "b","c", "d", "E");
my @rs;
foreach my $e (@arr2) {
    if(grep(!/^$e$/, @arr1)) { # if $e is not in @arr1
        push(@rs, $e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution is in the linked duplicate. The reason your code didn't work is because you put the negation in the wrong place - it should be `!grep {$e eq $_} @arr1`

Comment: Totally unrelated - it's somewhat in-joke hilarios to read "I don't write Perl very often" [from someone named Sawyer](http://perlresume.org/XSAWYERX) :)

Comment: @DVK What does the `!` in front of `//` mean? I saw this in perldoc: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html

Comment: `!` means "not". `!//` means "true if regex does NOT match". In other words, your code said "Find ALL entries in @arr1 that don't match $e". Presumably - unless @arr1 consists of ONLY $e elements - that's ALWAYS true, for any $e - meaning, you will push 100% of @arr2 into results.

Comment: @DVK, thanks, I also saw you're using a different `grep` syntax, is it preferable to write like your style or `grep($e eq $_, @arr1)`?

Comment: Personal preference. Perl Best Practices encourages not using parenthesis on builtins, but PbP isn't binding. As far as "eq":... don't use regex for mere "eq"... that's just not optimal :)

Comment: Note that your approach is very inefficient.

Comment: @ikegami from what aspect? regex? algorithm?

Comment: @Sawyer, It scans the entire string for each letter. In contrast, the accepted answer in the linked posted scans the string only once.

Comment: @Sawyer - if you're familiar with big-O notation, your solution is O(N^2) whereas the idiomatic one in the linked post is O(N)